Angular 18 hack for <select> with <input> in Signal() way to be optimized
I have a hack to implement a select box with dynamic  set and by double click to have this selection box with a indecently input box. The added new options will not double (by a Set) be sorted and at least available for the selection box options.
the code will be:
import { Component, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FormsModule
  ],
  template: `
    <h1>Selectbox with Input Option</h1>
    
<p> select / input-box will toggle by double click </p>
<p> input value will be take over by leaving the input box </p>
@if (!isInput()){
<select
  (dblclick)="isInput.set(!isInput())"
  [ngModel]="selectItem()"
  (change)="onSelectChange($any($event.target).value)">
>
 @for (item of  OptionValue(); track item) {
<option  >
  {{ item }}
</option>
 }
</select>} @else {
  <input
    (dblclick)="isInput.set(!isInput())"
    [ngModel]="selectItem()"
    (focusout)="onSelectChange($any($event.target).value)">
}
<hr>

  <p>show selected item:    {{selectItem()}}</p>

<hr>

  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Select with Input';

  public selectItem=signal('A');
  public OptionValue =signal(new Set<string>(['A','B','C']));
  protected isInput=signal(false)



  onSelectChange(item:string){
    this.selectItem.set(item);
   // this.OptionValue.update(items => { return[ ...items, item];})
    this.OptionValue().add(item);
    const OptionValueAy = Array.from(this.OptionValue()).sort();
    this.OptionValue().clear()
    OptionValueAy .forEach(item => this.OptionValue().add(item))
  }

} //end of class

For more details, please refer to stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-r9ar8j?file=src%2Fmain.ts
However, I am sure, that hack could be optimized. I looking fromward to your kind comments.
